# Bash script to compare output current to 5 minutes ago

Tags: bash, shell, rrdtool

I need to write a script in bash that takes last output from an rrd file like this:

```
#rrdtool lastupdate /home/usr/tmp/4880.rrd
```

The output has two columns and 3 lines, I can get to my desired value by using

```
#rrdtool lastupdate /home/usr/tmp/4880.rrd | grep -v ^$ | grep -v ^$ | awk '{print $2}'
```

This gives a numeric output for example 55600

Now I need to run this every 5 minutes and compare current value with the last value 5 minutes ago and if the difference is above a threshold than trigger an action that is another bash script.

Looking for ideas how to get this done.

Also is it possible to use rrdtool lastupdate to get the last and 2nd last value and compare and trigger the action if difference increases the threshold as this rrd database polls every 300 seconds (5 minutes.)

Answer (score 0):

Will this do?

```
THRESHOLD=100
while true; do
  VALUE=`rrdtool lastupdate /home/usr/tmp/4880.rrd | grep -v ^$ | grep -v ^$ | awk '{print $2}'`
  if [ -n "$OLDVALUE" ]; then
    if [ $VALUE -gt `expr $OLDVALUE '+' $THRESHOLD` ] || [ "$VALUE" -lt `expr $OLDVALUE - $THRESHOLD` ]; then
      echo "Oh noez, values are too different!!! new $VALUE old $OLDVALUE"
    fi
  fi
  sleep 300
  OLDVALUE=$VALUE
done
```